# Google Market API does not return results at all for all devices except mine

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an Android APP for searching some apps on Google Play, using Google Market API, latest version available (https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).
I've faced with such problem:

**Market API returns results only on my device. Tried it on 5 other devices - no result,except response "Error 429 - Bad request".**

Same APK, same app behaivor on different devices except API response 
He're is the code, if it helps.

Tried different e-mails and passwords for login (for my accounts, for device owneres accounts) - no effect.

```
androidId = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

MarketSession session = new MarketSession(false);

session.login(email,password, androidId);

Market.AppsRequest appsRequest = Market.AppsRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setQuery(query)
                    .setStartIndex(0)
                    .setEntriesCount(10)
                    .setWithExtendedInfo(true)
                    .build();

  MarketSession.Callback<Market.AppsResponse> callback = new MarketSession.Callback<Market.AppsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Market.ResponseContext context, Market.AppsResponse response) {
                    } else {
                        Log.d("APPS", "App Count in response: " + response.getAppCount());
                }

            };

  session.append(appsRequest, callback);
        }

session.flush();
```

Any help is welcome.
Maybe there are more up-to-date solutions (APIs, libraries etc.) for Android app searching? Including Google Play and other stores.

Comment: Did you try setting in place your google account on the other test devices (The one in the Settings menu)? This might just be the key.

Comment: Thank You, have tried it - has no effect.

Comment: The only thing I managed to find is the more detailed description "429Too Many Requests. The client has made too many requests and is currently being rate limited.", so first of all, you need to find the real cause of this problem: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#handling_api_errors . This link will help you find the error. That's about all I could find on the topic, I hope it helps.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/wiki/HowToGetAppComments says the limit is 1 request per 2 sec (~0,5 qps). So, you exceed it quite easily, if that's really true. I don't know then, how much time you have to wait until you may try again. Maybe there is another limit on that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an API Key (AKA Access Token) for you application?

My guess is that your issue lies somewhere in the process to register your application with Google that is causing this error, or perhaps the user authentication process. I would check to see that you have completed the whole process as necessary:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Also, a guide on how to properly authorize a Play API call:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization

Comment: The problem is not with official google play api. The authorization is different for it.

Comment: This way is not effective. It is not an official API and it's developers can change or update several time, therefore you will need change your code or approach several time. I created an app with this unofficial API, first time it worked well, then after 1 month crashed, and again became working, then crashed again. And this API can retrieve information not about all applications on the Market. I think that the developers have their own database and they update it when they want. I decided to do not use this API.

Comment: @Daryn What's that app you created? I'm sure it's an internal app used only inside your company and you can't tell us about it, right?

Comment: @Daryn, Which API are you talking about? The OAuth2, or the Google Play API? Either way it doesn't matter. They are both official APIs provided by Google. I have been using both of these APIs for quite some time now and i haven't had any problems. Before you go suggesting that the API is "wrong" or "bad" you should probably verify that the problem isn't in your code.